# How to download data from an SQL-database and annotate an MT4-chart

Tags: mql4

I have recently download the MetaTrader Terminal platform ( `MT4` ).

I have my own back testing engine which stores some output in my SQL-server database. The output depends on the model I am testing. However, the output can just be as simple as the time of entry of a trade.

**What I would like to know**

**Is it possible** in MQL4 to ***download*** data from a SQL-server database and then ***annotate*** the chart with a simple "**B**" for a buy entry or "**S**" for a sell entry?

So I have run a back test simulation ( i.e. EURUSD from 2010 to 2011 ) and stored the time of the buy and sell entries. I would then like to go to my MetaTrader 4 platform and run a script which would download the time of all the buy and sell entries from my SQL-database and on my EURUSD chart label these XTO-s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, this is possible

MQL4 language, incl the "*New*"-MQL4 ( aka MQL4.5 ), has syntactical support for importing DLL-based services, that allow re-integration of tools, the closed-syntax of the MQL4 does not allow to gain in a more natural way.

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+  // msMOD(s) 2014  >>> [dev]_test_(python)_.PUB__(mql).SUB_with_KBD_and_SIG___StatefullGrammarFSA
//| Ver 4.00, Build 509                          [dev]__********.mq4 |  // msMOD(s) 2013    
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+  //              
#property copyright "[dev] msMOD(s) (c) 1987-2014"                      //              
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------<#import>.start
#import  "msLIB_services.ex4"
         void  msLIB.aSnapshot.MAKE();
#import
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------<#import>.end
// ZMQ LIBRARY |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
#include <mql4zmq.mqh>                                                  // Include the libzmq.dll abstraction wrapper
// |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

This way your code, be it `MQL4-Script` or `MQL4-ExpertAdvisor` can communicate with external processes, incl. any reasonably working DBMS.

### Beware

There are few important features a code-design and integration architecture should bear in mind. MQL4, since the earliest days, is not a plain sequential-processor, namely the `MQL-CustomIndicator` is by far distant from this paradigm. The code ( except for the case of `MQL4-Script` ) acts as an event-driven factory, that is initiated by asynchronous flow of incoming Market Events. User is responsible for all measures to not violate real-time stability of this <kbd>Alpha</kbd>&<kbd>Omega</kbd> principle-of-MQL4-principles. In other words, a poor design, that may get some I/O-blocking ( due to RDBMS processing et al ), will be most probably a reason for Trading Terminal crash(es), which is the last thing anybody is willing to experience ( be it in live-trading or back-testing phase ), isn't it?

So, a sound non-blocking, heterogenous, parallel multi-processing integration architecture & code-design is to be used for this task.

### It works great, if done professionally

Keeping the said in mind allows very smart, fast and (almost) unlimited architectures to work together with Trading Terminal(s). Having multiple cases with near-real-time messaging between MT4/MQL4 code and AI/ML engine via python, fast FIX-Protocol streaming engine for real-time data input from Liquidity Pool provider, using a remote NVIDIA/GPU computation fabric, remote co-integrated IRC/skype/email Signal provisioning channels.

So a can do philosophy is in place. SQL is nothing extra in this sense. Puting labels is trivial in the same sense. Just of your imagination, MQL4 allows to build ( again, using a near-real-time design ) responsive/interactive GUI-layer, that allows, within a few [msec] stability barrier, work with the Trading Terminal in a pure-graphical manner ( long ago before a *One-Click-Trading* marketing tag came with just a click-To-Buy / click-To-Sell ) working fully interactively with line-controlled / graphical-objects visual trading aids, be it for a fully automated trade-execution ( with an indirect GUI-configuration of the rules-set ), or for an Augmented Trading style.

[image: Distributed-processing-MQL4-Cloud-xtrnSignalProvider]

### Yes, can make your MT4 Trading Terminal a sort of "remote-programmable charting display", driven not by FX-Market, but from a Cloud-processor, where your remote Strategy Testing Engine rulez ...

[image: Distributed-processing-MQL4-Cloud-Predictive-Technical-Analysis]

Comment: As I understand it (correct me if I'm wrong) the Expert Advisor & Custom Indicator are event driven so when a market event happens they are called. A script is not even driven so this is where I should create my code. Is it possible to stop the charts updating to get around the stability issue? As I'm back testing I'm not concerned with the charts updating.

Comment: Right, **`MQL4-Script`** has no trigger from an event queue, correct. Still, I would not rely on sending a blind SQL-querry & waiting, but rather implement an asynchronous proxy-interface, that would mediate MQL4-front-end / SQL-back-end processing & queue-management, to serve one after another, to avoid both MQL4-blocking and MQL4-side overload case, when getting an avalanche of bytes in the "block-buster" answer ( not mentioning the HFT-case scales as a first trouble in the list :o) )

Comment: Ask asked above, your code does not know, whether the **`MT4-Graph`** is an online, or an off-line one. You can easily activate your `MQL4-Script` code on an off-line graph, it does not "listen" to any updates nevertheless by-design. Another issue is to have "relevant OHLCV-data" already available in the MT4-HistoryCentre ( a database, from which your graphing will get PriceDOMAIN data to plot candles/bars ) -- but that is another subject to address.

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed answer. Think I get it and will now try go away and implement it. On the data issue I believe I can place my price data in the HistoryCenter.