# MT4 and website integration

Tags: trading, forex, mt4

my boss has requested that I make a website which allows people to sign up for forex trading and I'm quite a novice in this area, although I'm an experienced developer.

He requested that I look at the MT4 software and I did that, but I don't really understand how a desktop application can allow me to write a website to let people sign up, make payments and trade when this would require a windows machine to connect to.

Is this the best way to do this or is it just that he has seen MT4, loves it and think it's perfect, however it's not the way to write this kind of website?

The CRM will be using vtiger if that helps.  I'd appreciate any advice that you could give.

Comment: I think you should have access to services from eg. MT4, or any others that allows to send requests in order to trade. Do you have them ?

Comment: from more research that I have done I think MT4 desktop app communicates with the server online somewhere, so what you need is a server account with metatrader then you connect to their server, but this is what I'm hunting for information about now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A: MT4-Terminal integration path is open to any real-time process-to-process / grid-computing ( incl. "website integration" ). This is not an issue.

What IMHO matters more, than the technical integration, is a rather vague definition of the Project goal and the lack of a feasible & legal business model.

**"My boss has requested"** is not a good start for a serious Business Case and serious investors ( + count all those, who will get your offer to deposit their funds ) would most probably reject to finance your idea if no additional business model rationale and all detailed specifications would be assembled and presented.

FOREX trading is way more complicated than tromboning of PayP*l-deposits after a web-based login under a web-cast company or social-group image or CRM.

---

If interested in just the technical integration, check my posts on MT4 / MQL4 distributed processing solutions on StackOverflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27215797/3666197) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26583445/3666197) and do not hesitate to send me more questions on this subject.

Comment: sorry I didnt check my messages for a while, thanks for your answer!

Comment: @ChristopherThomas You are welcome, Christopher. There is definitely no need to be sorry. Life is so demanding and so fast paced ( and can be so fruitfull ). Hope you have enjoyed a few bits of inspiration. **How are you doing on the Fx-Project?** Have you already progressed to some further milestones in your principal architecture design? Do not hesitate to ask more.